# diff variables within a script

Tags: scripting, diff

I realize that the `diff` command is reserved for directories/files, but I've seen it being able to read from standard input, so that's not necessarily true.

Is it possible to somehow compare two variables that were stored in a `ksh` script?

The code looks like this:

```
a=$(cut -c 1-10 first_file.txt)
b=$(cut -f '3' -d ' ' second_file.txt)

#what I would like to do
$(diff $a $b) > differences.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Use process substution (thanks, Dennis!) [as described here](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3060/diff-will-usually-only-take-one-file-from-stdin.-this-is-a-method-to-take-the-result-of-two-streams-and-compare-with-diff.-the-example-i-use-to-compare-two-itunes-libraries-but-it-is-generally-applicable.). This would probably do it

```
diff <(echo $a) <(echo $b)
```

At least, that worked for me in bash on cygwin.

Comment: That's process substitution rather than input redirection.

Comment: Well, with the <, it's both, right?

Comment: Nope, I'm wrong, you're right.

Comment: Sorry, `ksh` doesn't like it.

Comment: So figure out the syntax for process substitution on ksh.

Comment: Looks like it might be ($(...)  from what Wikipedia tells me, so try : diff <($(echo $a)) <($(echo $b))